# JQuery selection help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This should be a simple answer for those who feel at home with selecting stuff with jquery, so here I go.

I have this piece of HTML:

```
<div class="cooljobdom-subdomains"> cooljobdom
    <div class="cooljob-subitem"> subitem
        <input class="variable_class" type="checkbox">
        <label> label 1
            <span class="AAA"></span>
            <span class="block-middle">city1</span>
            <span>address1</span>
           </label>
        </input>
    </div>
    <div class="cooljob-subitem"> subitem
        <input class="variable_class" type="checkbox">
        <label> label 2
            <span class="BBB"></span>
            <span class="block-middle" >city2</span>
            <span>address2</span>
           </label>
        </input>
    </div>
    <div class="cooljob-subitem"> subitem
        <input class="variable_class" type="checkbox">
        <label> label 3
            <span class="CCC"></span>
            <span class="block-middle">city3</span>
            <span>address3</span>
           </label>
        </input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have the following string as the result of the selection:
city1,address1; city2,address2; city3,address3.

sofar I have this selection:

```
var value = $(".cooljobdom-subdomains .cooljob-subitem .block-middle").text();
value += $(".cooljobdom-subdomains .cooljob-subitem .block-middle").next().text();
alert(value);
```

but this gives me city1city2city3address1address2address3.

Keep in mind that there is a variable number of divs with "cooljob-subitem" class.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not the most efficient solution, but you can try the following. With `each()` function you make a loop on every `cooljob-subitem` element. Then you can look in its descendants with `find()`, and finally get html content with `html()`.

```
var result = '';

$('.cooljob-subitem').each(function()
{
    result += $(this).find('.block-middle').html() + ',';
    result += $(this).find('span:last-child').html() + ';';
});

result = result.slice(0,-1);

alert(result);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9LLe5nb/2/)

Comment: This solution also adds a semi-colon at the end of the result. It's better to add the city,address pair into an array and then join the array using the semicolon character

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var value = $(".cooljobdom-subdomains .cooljob-subitem .block-middle").map(function () {
    return $(this).text() + ',' + $(this).addBack().text()
}).get().join(';');
console.log(value)
```

Comment: close, this returns city1,city1;city2,city2;city3,city3.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this within the each function.

```
var value = "";
$(".cooljob-subitem").each(function(){
    value += $(this).find("span").text();
});
console.log(value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v1xou7h7/

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = "";
var len = $(".cooljobdom-subdomains .cooljob-subitem .block-middle").length;
$(".cooljobdom-subdomains .cooljob-subitem .block-middle").each(function(index, element){
    value += $(this).text() + "," + $(this).next().text();
    if (index < len - 1) {
        value += "; ";
    } else {
       value += ".";
    }
});
alert(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

its because you have three classes called ".block-middle"

best solution would be if you go through **each** of the classes.

```
$('.block-middle').each(function(){
    // you now can get each of the elements with $(this) - so..

    var value1 = $(this).text;
    var value2 = $(this).next().text();
    var text = value1 + ', ' + value2;

    alert(text);
});
```

greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in 1 line like so.

http://jsfiddle.net/or18dus3/1/

```
var value = $.map($(".cooljobdom-subdomains .cooljob-subitem  .block-middle"), function(obj, i){
   return $(obj).text().concat(",", $(obj).next().text());
}).join(";");
```